# How To implement swapfile cross operating system

Tags: rust, ram, memory-efficient, swapfile

There are use cases where I can't have a lot of ram, and sometimes due to docker based services doesn't always provide more than 512mb/1gb of ram, or if I run multiple rust based gui apps and if each take 100mb of ram normally, how can I implement a swapfile/ virtual ram to exceed allotted ram? Also os level swapfiles don't let users choose which app can use real ram and which swapfile, so it can become a problem too. I want to use swapfile as much as possible, and not even real ram, if possible. Users and hosting services provide with lot of storage usually (more than 10gb normally) so it would be a good way to use the available storage too!
If swapfile or anything like that aren't possible, I would like to know if there is any difference in speed and cpu consumption between "cache data in ram" apps and "cache data in file and read it when required" apps. If the latter is slow normally and not as efficient as swapfiles, I would like to know the possible ways how os manages to make swapfiles that efficient than apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application does not control whether the memory they allocate is allocated on real RAM, on a swap partition, or else. You just ask for memory, and the OS is responsible for finding available memory to give to you.

Besides that, note that using swap (sometimes called *swapping*) is **extremely** bad performance-wise. How much depends a lot on your hardware, but it's about three orders of magnitude. This is even amplified if you are interacting with a user: a program that is fetching some resources will not be too bothered if it has to wait one minute to get them instead of a few milliseconds because the system is under heavy load, but a user will generally not be that patient.

Also note that, when swapping, the OS does not chose which application gets the faster RAM and which ones get the swap memory *at random*. It will try to determine which application should be prioritized, by how much, etc. based on how it was configured (at least for the Linux kernel), so in reality it's the user who, in the end, decides which applications get the most RAM (ahead of time, of course: they are not prompted each time the kernel has to make that decision with a little pop-up...).

Finally, modern OS allow several applications to allocate memory that overlap, as long as each application is not fully using the memory it asked for (which is kind of usual), allowing you to run applications that in theory require more RAM that you actually have.

This was on the OS part: now to the application part. Usually, when you write a program (whose purpose is not specifically RAM-related), you should not really care for memory consumption (up to a certain point), especially in Rust. Not only that is usually handled by the OS in case you used a little bit too much memory, but when it's possible, most people prefer to trade a little more memory usage (even a *lot* more) for better CPU performance, because RAM is a lot cheaper than CPU.

There are exceptions, of course, in which the memory consumption is so high that you can't really afford not paying attention. In these cases, either you let the user deal with this problem (ie. this application is known to consume a lot of memory because there are no other ways to do this, so if you want to use it, just have a lot of memory), as often video games do, or you rethink your application to reduce the memory usage trading it for some CPU efficiency, as for example is done when you are handling graphs so huge you couldn't even store them on all the hard disks of the world (in which case your application has to be smart enough to be able to work on small parts of the graph at the time), or finally you are working with a big resource but which can be stored on the hard disk, so you just write it on a file and access it chunks-by-chunks, as some database managers do.